# Why does the function name in .o file different from the one in .cc file after compiling?

Tags: linux, function, compiler-construction, makefile, g++

I compiled an .cc file with the following command, which is in Makefile code:

```
bin/bash ../libtool --silent --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
-I.. -I../include/ -I..    -g -O2 -MT rtpsession_inet.lo -MD -MP -MF 
.deps/rtpsession_inet.Tpo -c -o rtpsession_inet.lo rtpsession_inet.cc
```

There is a function named **rtp_session_rtp_recv** in the .cc file. However, it is said that the reference of this function cannot be found when I use the library generated by the Makefile.

So I checked the .o file generated by rtpsession_inet.cc and find that there is not a function named **rtp_session_rtp_recv** while the function name is changed to **_Z20rtp_session_rtp_recvP11_RtpSessionj**.

Meanwhile, there are several other functions changes their name, e.g. **rtp_session_rtp_send** -> **_Z20rtp_session_rtp_sendP11_RtpSessionP4msgb**.

But functions such as **rtp_session_set_remote_addr_full** are not changed at all.

What is the additional characters' meaning? How can I deal with this problem?

I compile the file in Linux and use command

```
nm rtpsession_inet.o
```

to read the .o file. (All the functions including the one with incorrect name are with T tag, which means the reference exists)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is name mangling, and how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314743/what-is-name-mangling-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: But it doesn't works....... It seems that name mangling is a normal mechanism. I'm not sure whether the difference of name would have effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

It's for the benefit of the linker. A C++ compiler is able to resolve multiple functions of the same name, based on their argument types. For example, you might have a function called `print` that takes an `int` argument, and another that takes a `char*` argument. The compiler knows which one to generate a call to based on what type of argument you pass to it.

Calls across translation units, though, have to be resolved by the linker, which typically is not aware of C++ overloading rules and has to resolve calls based only on the name. So the C++ compiler decorates the name with enough information to resolve the overload.

The C++ standard doesn't specify how this is done, but if you look at the name you can probably work out how the mangled name is generated.

> How can I deal with this problem?

The compiler and linker should resolve calls correctly. What problem are you referring to?

Comment: I met the problem in a project and the final result of the project is a library (.so) file. When trying to compile another sample program using this library, it is said that: `/usr/local/lib//libortp.so: undefined reference to rtp_session_rtp_recv`. I don't know why it cannot find the reference and suspect that it is caused by the difference of the function name. BTW, the command I used to compile the sample program is  `g++ -L /usr/local/lib/ -I /usr/local/include/ortp/ -I /usr/include/ rtpsend.c -o rtpsend  -lortp`.

Comment: @zzy Take a look at 'extern "C"{}' to avoid mangling straight C calls.

Comment: When I add `extern "C"` to the head of `int rtp_session_rtp_recv (RtpSession * session, uint32_t user_ts)', it is said that 'rtpsession_priv.h:49:5: error: previous declaration of 'int rtp_session_rtp_recv(RtpSession*, uint32_t)' with 'C++' linkage
`. And when after adding `extern "C"` to the head file as well, it is said that `rtpsession_priv.h:49:8: error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant`. So how can I use it?

Comment: `extern "C"` is valid only in C++ code. If you need it in a header to be `#include`d by both C and C++ source files, you need to enclose it in `#include __cplusplus`. See [this section](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) of the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/) for information on mixing C and C++ code.

Comment: @zzy: Are you mixing C and C++ code in the same program? If so, you should have mentioned that in your question rather than assuming name mangling is the problem and just asking about that. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: That's true! Name mangling is only one possibility I find. Because I don't know it before, it seems serious to me before asking this question. Also , do you mean `#define __cplusplus` when you mentioned `#include __cplusplus`? It really looks strange maybe....

Comment: @zzy: No, I meant **`#ifdef __cplusplus`**; sorry about that.

Comment: @KeithThompson: It seems that the __cplusplus has been defined yet in the program. And the declaration `extern "C" int rtp_session_rtp_recv (RtpSession * session, uint32_t user_ts)` in the head file isn't compiled, which caused an error called `implicit declaration of function`. So how can I use `extern "C"` in the .h file? I am still confused.

Comment: `__cplusplus` is always predefined for C++ code, and is never predefined for C code. `extern "C"` is used in C++ code, and is a syntax error in C code. That's why you need to surround it with `#ifdef __cplusplus`. Please read the [C++ FAQ section](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) on mixing C and C++; it explains this better than I could.

Answer (score 0):

The additional characters are symbol "decorations" added by the compiler and are used to identify the function/method signature, i.e. the return type and the parameters. It helps the runtime determine which one of many functions of the same name (overloading) to invoke in any given invocation.