# Need Help in C++ Disasm

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I do some C++ disassembling with IDA Pro. But I often see lines likes these.

```
call    __ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc ;std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,char  const*)
```

What are these glyphs about? Why does the C++ function look so complex? And how can I simplify my ASM. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The symbol name contains information about the return type and parameter count and types of a function. This is done to allow for, among other things, function overloading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the function name in .o file different from the one in .cc file after compiling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243578/why-does-the-function-name-in-o-file-different-from-the-one-in-cc-file-after-c) and/or [What is name mangling, and how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1314743)

Comment: `Options -> Demangled names -> [x] Names`
This should make it a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

C++ ensures that overloaded functions can be distinguished by the linker by [mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) their names. What you are seeing is type information encoded in the mangled function name.

Answer (score 2):

That is the output function for (for example)

```
cout << "something";
```

`std::operator<<` is the name of the function. It takes a `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>&` argument - in other words, `std::ostream` The second argument is a `char const *`, in other words, a classic C style string that isn't supposoed to change.

Since `operator<<` also returns a `std::ostream&`, this is encoded before the name

It's "complicated" because it's easier to define one, templated, `basic_ostream` since there are various types of streams, such as `owstream` that takes "wide chars", it's useful to have a templated `basic_ostream` that can be instantiated to form a `std::ostream`, than to have to implement several different, essentially the same, stream classes.