# Calling C function in Objective-C block (Linker error)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c, linker

I have created C function:

header

```
//FileSystem.h file
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
BOOL AddSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(NSURL *url);
```

implementation

```
//FileSystem.mm
#import "FileSystem.h"
#import <sys/xattr.h>
#import <Support/Support.h>

static const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
BOOL AddSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(NSURL *url) {
    BOOL operationResult = NO;
    // some implementation
    return operationResult;
}
```

When i'm calling `AddSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL` from another parts of application everything is OK, except one place where i'm calling function from the block.

```
__block UpdateFileAsyncOperation* selfOperation = self;
    _contentDownloader.completionBlock = ^(NSData* data) {
        [data saveForcedToPath:selfOperation.filePath];
        NSURL* fileUrlWithScheme = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:selfOperation.filePath];
        AddSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(fileUrlWithScheme);
        [runLoop removePort:port forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [selfOperation completeOperation];
    };
```

In that place ,while linking in progress, there is error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "*AddSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL", referenced from:
>         _*_36-[UpdateFileAsyncOperation start]_block_invoke in UpdateFileAsyncOperation.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
>   i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

I don't understand why it happens, how it depends on block? and how can I fix that?
Thanks!

**Update:** it is not dependent on block, i have moved calling of function to another place of class: the error still there. I'm trying to find why

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is name mangling, and how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314743/what-is-name-mangling-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
It not dependent on block. It dependent on file extensions.

The problem file was with ".m" extension, other files was with ".mm" extension.

So I have putted next macro in FileSystem.h file

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

BOOL AddSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(NSURL *url);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```