# What does "@@YAHXZ" mean in VS link error description?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

i would like to understand the `@@YAHXZ`  part of such an error:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl func2(void)"
>   (?func2@@YAHXZ) referenced in function _main  .

this is just one example but i've seen other types of strange letters i just dont remember them right now. where can i find an explanation on each of them?

Comment: Here is the key: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names

Comment: Read about name mangling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314743/what-is-name-mangling-and-how-does-it-work) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). Keep in mind every implementation has it's own name decorating scheme, which can change  due to compiler flags and with every compiler version.

Answer (score 4):

This is called «[name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)», or «name decoration».

As C++ supports function overloading, the name of the symbols are generated in a specific way, usually based on the argument's types.

Here's the official documentation on Microsoft website:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx

**EDIT**

Microsoft doesn't provide a complete documentation about name decoration.
If you're interested in knowing exactly what the symbols mean, I recommend reading **Agner Fog's documentation on calling conventions**:
http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately, the official documentation does not document the actual scheme used. It only explains in general terms what a decorated name is. [This source](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling) seems to explain in more detail though it's a wiki and doesn't specify for which versions it's accurate.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's right, unfortunately. Added a link to provide more infos on this.