# What is the purpose of a linkage declaration for "linkage purposes" only, as explained in [dcl.typedef]/9?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[dcl.typedef]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef#9):

If the typedef declaration defines an unnamed class (or enum), the first typedef-name declared by the declaration to be that class type (or enum type) is used to denote the class type (or enum type) for linkage purposes only ([basic.link]). [ Note: A typedef declaration involving a lambda-expression does not itself define the associated closure type, and so the closure type is not given a name for linkage purposes. — end note ] [ Example:

```
typedef struct { } *ps, S;      // S is the class name for linkage purposes
typedef decltype([]{}) C;       // the closure type has no name for linkage purposes
```

— end example ]

Answer (score 2):

In the latest working draft, the reference is [[dcl.typedef]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef#4).

The significance of "for linkage purposes" is given by [[basic.link]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#8):

> Two declarations of entities declare the same entity if, considering declarations of unnamed types to introduce their names for linkage purposes, if any ([dcl.typedef], [dcl.enum]), they correspond ([basic.scope.scope]), have the same target scope that is not a function or template parameter scope, and either
>
> - they appear in the same translation unit, or
> - they both declare names with module linkage and are attached to the same module, or
> - they both declare names with external linkage.
>
> [*Note 2*: There are other circumstances in which declarations declare the same entity ([dcl.link], [temp.type], [temp.spec.partial]).
> — *end note*]

So let's consider the following example:

```
// S1.h
struct S1 {
    int member;
};

// A.cpp
#include "S1.h"
extern S1 s1;

// B.cpp
#include "S1.h"
S1 s1;
```

After preprocessing, `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` will be as follows:

```
// A.cpp
struct S1 {
    int member;
};
extern S1 s1;

// B.cpp
struct S1 {
    int member;
};
S1 s1;
```

Each translation unit contains the definition of a struct named `S1`. Is `A.cpp`'s `S1` the *same* struct as `B.cpp`'s `S1`? If the answer is yes, then  then `B.cpp`'s definition of the object `S1 s1;` links with `A.cpp`'s declaration `extern S1 s1;`. If the answer is no, then the two translation units declare the same variable with different types, and the program is ill-formed (no diagnostic required).

Well, you probably know that we would be in big trouble if `B.cpp`'s definition of `s1` were not a definition of `A.cpp`'s `s1`. It must be the case that both translation units are defining the *same* type `S1`.

[basic.link]/8 tells us that this is indeed so. Both declarations of `S1` declare it with external linkage. Both have the same target scope---namely, the global scope. And they correspond because they both introduce the same name; [basic.scope.scope]/4:

> Two declarations *correspond* if they (re)introduce the same name, both declare constructors, or both declare destructors, unless [*irrelevant exceptions omitted*].

So both declarations declare the same type. `A.cpp`'s `S1` *is* the same type as `B.cpp`'s `S1`. `A.cpp`'s `s1` has the same type as `B.cpp`'s `s1`.

Now let's change the example slightly:

```
// S2.h
typedef struct {
    int member;
} S2;

// C.cpp
#include "S2.h"
extern S2 s2;

// D.cpp
#include "S2.h"
S2 s2;
```

After preprocessing:

```
// C.cpp
typedef struct {
    int member;
} S2;
extern S2 s2;

// D.cpp
typedef struct {
    int member;
} S2;
S2 s2;
```

Does this work the same way as the other example?

Well, each typedef declaration introduces the typedef name `S2`, and [basic.link]/8 tells us that these two declarations declare the same "entity" `S2`. But we must keep in mind that the kind of "entity" being declared here is a typedef name, not a type. In other words the program only contains *one* typedef name known as `S2`. But the question is whether both translation units declare `S2` to be aliases to the *same* type. If not, the program is ill-formed (no diagnostic required).

In other words, in order for this program to be correct, it must be that `struct { int member }` in `C.cpp` declares the same type as `struct { int member }` in `D.cpp`.

And here, [dcl.typedef]/4 saves us. It tells us that both `C.cpp` and `D.cpp`, by defining an unnamed struct in a typedef declaration that makes `S2` an alias for that struct, give the struct the name `S2` "for linkage purposes". Then, when we use [basic.link]/8 to determine whether those two structs are the *same* struct, we are instructed to consider them to have the names that they have for linkage purposes. This makes them *correspond* under [basic.scope.scope]/4, so they declare the same type.

If the "for linkage purposes" rule didn't exist, then they wouldn't correspond (because, if neither one has a name, then we can't claim that they both have the same name) and the program would be ill-formed (no diagnostic required).

If you're wondering why anyone would write `typedef struct { int member; } S2;` in the first place, the answer is that you probably wouldn't do this in pure C++, but this practice is common in C, and you might be including a C header into your C++ program. So for *historical reasons*, C++ has to have a special rule to support linking together such declarations.

(But then why does C allow it? It's because C doesn't use "name-based linkage" for types the way that C++ does. It instead uses the concept of "compatible types", which I won't delve into here.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you parsed that correctly. What this is saying that in this kind of declaration the "name for linkage purposes" will be determined this way. You need to have a name for the type if it ever comes up in function arguments somewhere (see [What is name mangling, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314743/what-is-name-mangling-and-how-does-it-work) )