# Are only C defined data types allowed during an extern "C" within C++?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a dynamic library, is it possible to have a function output a custom class object when using `extern "C"` or am I limited to data types native to C.

For example, could I have

```cpp
extern "C" std::string func(const std::string& str);
```

So that I can get that function and use it after loading the library and getting the function symbol?

```cpp
std::string result = func("Lol");
```

Comment: See if this bears any interest: [extern "C" function return types](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-help/2011-02/msg00393.html) (GCC mailing list)

Comment: Interesting compiler differences clang and MSVC issue a warning, but GCC compiles ok - live - https://godbolt.org/z/1KnPT8hPE

Comment: The point of extern C is to remove C++'s name mangling and allow the names to be understood by C (or a language that accepts a C interface). You could return a `std::string`, but there isn't much point. The other language won't know what a `std::string` is.

Comment: You can have C++ types in `extern "C"` function but you can neither create nor access those types from C. They have to be `void *` or pointers to abstract types. The C compiler has no idea how to provide storage for the `std::string` returned by `func` so that can't work. You have to return a `std:string&` or `std:string*` that the C side can treat as `void*` or pointer to an abstract `struct CppString;`. You also will need to provide an `extern "C"` function to delete the string later.

Comment: The comments here pretend that `extern "C"` only exists to interface with C. It does not. Dart FFI, for example, has no problems using functions with C++ types. Like was said, the point is just to not mangle the names.

Comment: @sweenish: Even if Dart thinks it knows how to handle C++ types, C++ disagrees.  You have undefined behavior all over the place if memory allocation and constructor calls are done by anything not the C++ compiler, if member function calls are done through anything except a C++ member-access expression (possibly a pointer-to-member application expression).  And so on and so forth.  Perhaps a specific implementation is documented to conform to a specific ABI covering the entire C++ language that makes doing these things from another language possible.  But in general it is not.

Comment: @BenVoigt I guess it's a good thing that Dart FFI expects you to compile your C++ to a dynamic library then.

Comment: @sweenish: That's helpful but by no means sufficient.

Comment: I'm just more willing to think that the people at Google who introduced this did their homework, I guess.

Comment: Having to use `extern "C"` should be a sign for caution about not too extensive C++ compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

```
extern "C" std::string func(const std::string& str);
```

[will give func C-style linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c). `func` will not be [mangled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314743/what-is-name-mangling-and-how-does-it-work) to allow for fun C++ tricks like overloading.

It won't prevent the function from accepting or returning a C++ type, but the calling language will have to know how to interpret the type. For types that are not Standard layout, trivial types (what we used to call [POD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType)) this will be difficult-to-impossible.

Side note: Since Standard Library implementations can differ, this can be problematic for a type like `std::string` even if the caller is C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

From the standard:

> Linkage from C++ to objects defined in other languages and to objects defined in C++ from other languages
> is implementation-defined and language-dependent. Only where the object layout strategies of two language
> implementations are similar enough can such linkage be achieved.

In the context of your question, I interpret this to mean: **Yes, you can use C linkage** (to skip mangling/simplify symbol names) **on C++-specific objects and types, but the environment referencing those symbols needs to be specified such that it can make sense of those objects.** As your linking environment is *also* C++, this should not be a problem, assuming you use binary-compatible versions of the C++ standard library/STL on "both sides".