# How to understand UnboundTypeError in Emscripten

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

I have a large C++ codebase that produces WebAssembly modules with Emscripten. When I add new properties to objects that are returned from WebAssembly, I often get `UnboundErrorType` in a format like this:

```
Cannot call MyModule.myFunc due to unbound types:
N2XY7Something26DateObjectTILNS0_15OptionalMembersE1ENS_5DateTINS0_12DateObjectEEES4_EE

Cannot call MyModule.myFunc due to unbound types:
NSt3__28optionalIN2XY7Something12DateObjectEEE, NSt3__28optionalIN2XY5DateTINS1_7XY12DateObjectEEEEE
```

Although I'm not looking for a specific solution but rather an explanation, this is usually caused by code that looks like this:

```cpp
auto getDay  ( XY::Something::DateObject const & d ) { return d.getDay  (); }
auto getMonth( XY::Something::DateObject const & d ) { return d.getMonth(); }
auto getYear ( XY::Something::DateObject const & d ) { return d.getYear (); }

void dummyDateObjectSet( XY::DateObject &, bool ) {}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS( MyObject )
{
    value_object< XY::DateObject >( "DateObject" )
        .field( "day"  , getDay  , dummyDateObjectSet )
        .field( "month", getMonth, dummyDateObjectSet )
        .field( "year" , getYear , dummyDateObjectSet );
}
```

I get the general idea of why this error is happening, but I've got no idea how to interpret these identifiers like `N2`, `7`, `ILNS0_15`, `EEES4_EE` and similar. I assume they represent data types in a C++ way, but since I come from a JavaScript background, I have no idea how to read these.

Is there any reference or documentation (or maybe common knowledge) that explains how to understand this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my original assumption was completely wrong.

This is caused by [name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314743/what-is-name-mangling-and-how-does-it-work) technique.

It's possible to decode mangled names (similar to URI decoding) to get human-readable information with this approach:

```
# Ignore that this code may not make sense, it's just to showcase the tool
echo "NSt3__28optionalIN2XY9Something10DateObjectEEE, NSt3__28optionalIN2XY5DateTINS1_2XY10DateObjectEEEEE" | c++filt -t
std::__2::optional<XY::Something::DateObject>, std::__2::optional<XY::DateT<XY::XY::DateObject> >
```