# Import DLL | Ctypes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am trying to import the functions of the DLL comes in the package XFLR5.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xflr5/files/6.59/

I have 2 questions.

1. The function names look very different to what is being declared in the source file
   https://sourceforge.net/p/xflr5/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/xflr5/XFoil-lib/xfoil.cpp
   Some functions are listed below which came out from

objdump -p XFoil.dll

```
    [   0] ??0XFoil@@QEAA@AEBV0@@Z
    [   1] ??0XFoil@@QEAA@XZ
    [   2] ??1XFoil@@UEAA@XZ
    [   3] ??4XFoil@@QEAAAEAV0@AEBV0@@Z
    [   4] ??_7XFoil@@6B@
    [   5] ?CheckAngles@XFoil@@QEAA_NXZ
    [   6] ?ClSpec@XFoil@@QEBANXZ
    [   7] ?DeRotate@XFoil@@QEAANXZ
    [   8] ?ExecMDES@XFoil@@QEAAXXZ
    [   9] ?ExecQDES@XFoil@@QEAA_NXZ
    [  10] ?Gauss@XFoil@@AEAA_NHQEAY05NQEAN@Z
```

Given the above, What is the method from above list corresponds to the constructor of this class

```
XFoil::XFoil()
{
    m_pOutStream = nullptr;
    //------ primary dimensioning limit parameters
```

2. When I import the DLL and, try to call function naca4 I get the below error.

```
void XFoil::naca4(int ides, int nside)
{
    int n1=0, n2=0, n3=0, n4=0, ib=0, i=0;
    //    double xx[nside], yt[nside], yc[nside], xb[2*nside], yb[2*nside]
```

```
from ctypes import *
lib= WinDLL("XFoil.dll") 
naca4 = getattr(lib, '?naca4@XFoil@@QEAAXHH@Z')
```

```
# >>> naca4(2412,100)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x000000000009314C
```

Could someone please point out what is causing this error and how to avoid this ?
Also, do I have to use getattr(lib, 'xxxx') for each and every function before calling them or will they become apparent automatically when the constructor is called ?

Comment: You are trying to call a C++ object method from “C”types. This isn’t supported.

Comment: C++ has [name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314743/what-is-name-mangling-and-how-does-it-work) to enable function overloading. But Python does not. If you want to work with XFLR5 maybe you can look into [xflrpy](https://github.com/nikhil-sethi/xflrpy)

Comment: Thanks. and sorry for the late reply. So this name mangling can be handled via setting the method names explicitly via getattr for each method. How do you find the constructor method from this method list to begin with though